# Vim can multi-paste like vscode?

Tags: vim, ide, vim-plugin

I'm a really big fan of VSCode, But I wanna migrate to vim...

vim has a alternative way, like vscode?

I know multi cursor plugin, But I don't know multi copy and multi paste with orderly.

[image]

Comment: :h visual-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plug-in [mg979/vim-visual-multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi), that implements something akin to multiple cursors in Vim.

Without plug-ins, Vim has a feature of Visual Block selection, but that is column based, so when you use it to perform this operation (in the same sequence you used), you end up with this instead:

```
<div>Multi-copy</div>
<div>Paste     </div>
<div>Orderly   </div>
```

(You can later use something else, like a `:s`, to remove the spaces before the `</div>`.)

Another option would be to use a Vim macro, to yank the contents of a single line, position the cursor inside one of the `<div>` blocks and put it there, then position the cursor at the next line, so that the next macro execution will act on the second line, then keep repeating the macro until done.

In Vim, it's actually more natural to do the opposite of what you've done, instead of putting the contents inside the `<div>`s, putting the `<div>`s around the contents is much easier. You can use Visual Block insert and append, even Visual Block put will work for the left tag (they have all the same length), there are also common plug-ins (such as vim-surround) to surround a selection in a specific HTML tag, and plug-ins (such as emmet.vim) to quickly generate a structure with a set of HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have at least two options on neovim for doing that:

1 - Using (nvim) inccommand like:

```
:%s/<div>\zs/whetever you want/g

 the \zs ensures your changes will start after this position
```

2 - Using visual block selection

```
Start visual block selection -> Ctrl-v
use j or k to expand your selection
now press I and type what you want, after that 
just press Esc.
```